# If pointers are just integers that hold an address (4 bytes - 32 bits), how do they store the extra addresses in 64-bit memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, 64-bit

When using the sizeof() function in c++ programs, the pointers I've looked at seem to all return a size of 4 bytes. I've seen online that pointers are just integer memory addresses. How does this make sense in 64 bit architectures that would then potentially have memory addresses that cannot be accessed in 4 bytes?

Comment: In 64-bit achitecture you'd (probably) get `sizeof(void*) == 8`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. My pc is 64 bit and it returns 4 for sizeof(void*)?

Comment: Then you are compiling for 32bit.  Check the compiler options (or  tell us the compiler you are using).

Comment: Most modern 64-bit operating systems support a 32-bit mode for backward-compatibility. If `sizeof(void*) == 4` with you, then you are probably targetting a 32-bit platform, i.e. your program will run in 32-bit mode. Check your compiler's documentation on how to build a 64-bit program.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern 64-bit operating systems support a 32-bit mode for backward-compatibility. If `sizeof(void*) == 4` with you, then you are probably targetting the 32-bit platform of your operating system, so that your program will run in 32-bit mode.

Check your compiler's documentation on how to target the 64-bit platform of your operating system. Afterwards, you should notice that `sizeof(void*) == 8`.

Answer (score 0):

> If pointers are just integers that hold an address (4 bytes - 32 bits), how do they store the extra addresses in 64-bit memory?

A 32 bit pointer **cannot** store 64 bit addresses. This is why pointers are 64 bits on 64 bit systems.